# Custom decoder for images

Tags: swift, serialization, decoder, decodable

I would like to create a `Decoder` that can deserialize some types from the data. I would like it to be able to automatically deserialize all the types, that have `init?(data: Data)` initializer using this init method.

```
protocol DataInitializable: Decodable {
    init?(data: Data)
}
extension DataInitializable {
    // ???
}
extension UIImage: DataInitializable {}
let decoder = DataDecoder()
let image = try? decoder.decode(UIImage.self, from: data)
```

I have tried various things, but I can't find a proper way to implement this kind of decoder. Also I'm not sure how to implement `Decodable` protocol in `DataInitializable` extension so that it works using `init(data:)`.

I know that I could use wrapper class for the image, or something similar, but I would like to have this kind of decoder instead.